# Is branch.io free of charge for using only deep links?

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, branch.io

My team wants to substitute Firebase Dynamic Links with Branch.io links. We decided to move, because we want to go from the Stores and distribute applications internally, and Firebase deep links don't work with deferred deep linking on Android if the app was not installed from Play Store.

For the deep links creating we use our back-end that makes POST call to Firebase (in the future Branch.io) to create link and send it to the users. This link redirects to our website, if the app is not installed, or to the application, if it's installed. All we need is to receive in application entry some parameters to sign up user correctly.

Will be that logic free for us, because I don't understand in what cases MAUs are counted? Also we have live application and count of MAUs equals 0, however we are already using deep links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note a Branchster Here:

By default, all Branch Links are deep links and deferred deep links. You can make use of Branch [Dashboard](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/create-quick-links)/[API](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/deep-linking-api#endpoint---create)/[SDK](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-advanced-features#create-deep-link) to create these links. Once the user installs and then opens your app, you can [deep link](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/creating-a-deep-link) based on the link data.

For Pricing related details please check - https://branch.io/pricing/
Also please reach out to our [Billing team](http://billing@branch.io) for more details on the same.

Comment: Hi @Katrik, thank you for your reply. I'm already using Branch.io deep links among the team members, but MAUs equals 0 and I have only 'click' events. Is it counted at the end of the month?

Comment: Hey @OdarynaKorolevych yes that's correct. However please reach out to our billing team for more insights on the same.

Comment: They billed me $5 for 1k MAU over 10k ($45 total) for 100% organic traffic and 0 value provided by Branch. Be careful.

Comment: Though if you have a significant portion of paid traffic, it's still a good value.